# awaitMessages code not applying outside the block

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to get it to run `client.editData` (function I edited it's basically a sqlite3 changer), when it does it doesn't apply to the database and when I change a variable there it doesn't change outside of `awaitMessages`.

- note: the `.editData` has nothing wrong with it

```js
interaction.channel.awaitMessages({
    filter,
    max: 1,
    time: 10000,
    errors: ['time']
}).then((collected) => {
    var amountXP = Math.round(Math.random() * 3);
    if (amountXP === 0) {
        amountXP = 1;
    }
    // THIS RUNS BUT IT DOESN'T RUN OUTSIDE OF THE .THEN
    client.editData(collected.first().author, collected.first().guild, 'xp', 1, 'add', );
    interaction.followUp(`${collected.first().author} got the correct answer it was **${
        collected.first().content
      }** and got **${amountXP}** xp`, );
}).catch((collected) => {
    interaction.followUp('no one got the answer it was **' + q.answer[0] + '**', );
});
```

- I tried using a callback function
- I was expecting it to run `client.getData` and the changes happening outside of `.then`

Comment: I'm not sure if I can understand your question. Why do you want to run `client.editData` outside of that `then` if you're working with the `collected` messages?

Comment: "I tried using a callback function" — Well, that's what you passed to `then` and you say it is working. Did you mean some other callback function?

Comment: "I was expecting it to run client.getData" — Your code doesn't mention `getData`: why would it run it?

Comment: the client.getData` is outside of the snippet I sent

Comment: @SirPixel — Please read [ask]; provide a [mcve]

Comment: I don't get what your not getting, you can reproduce by putting a variable outside of awaitMessages and change it inside of awaitMessages and then log it